# Checking if a polynomial contains a certain monomial

Tags: pattern-matching, polynomials

I want to check if a given polynomial contains a certain monomial while ignoring ordering of the variables. For example:
$$P(a,b,c)=abc + bca$$
And then I want to check if $P$ contains $bac$ (should be true). I tried FreeQ and MemberQ but both return false.

Comment: Isn’t `FreeQ[]` —> `False` just the result you want?  (I guess you realize that $P$ is just $2 abc$, though.)

Comment: Not exactly, for example FreeQ[a*b*c, a*b]=False also

Comment: Have you seen `MonomialList`?

Comment: I guess I could do something like: MemberQ[MonomialList[a*b*c], a*c*b] but that wont work if there is a coefficient other than 1.

Comment: Perhaps `MemberQ[MonomialList[2 a b c], Optional[_?NumericQ] a c b]`?

Comment: This seems to work! Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
MemberQ[MonomialList[2 a b c], Optional[_?NumericQ] a c b]
(*  True  *)
```

Also this, which is a more algebraic approach.

```
With[{vars = {a, b, c, d}}, 
 KeyExistsQ[CoefficientRules[a b + 2 a b c + a b c d, vars], 
  First@Keys@CoefficientRules[a c b, vars]]
 ]
(*  True  *)
```

It's important that the variables be the same in the same order in both calls to `CoefficientRules`.  (I tend to prefer algebraic approaches in dealing with polynomials.)

Another algebraic approach:

```
With[{vars = {a, b, c, d}},
   With[{monomial = CoefficientArrays[a b c, vars]},
    CoefficientArrays[a b + 2 a b c + a b c d, 
       vars][[Length@monomial]] * Last@monomial
    ]]@"NonzeroPositions" =!= {}
(*  True  *)

With[{vars = {a, b, c, d}},
   With[{monomial = CoefficientArrays[a d c, vars]},
    CoefficientArrays[a b + 2 a b c + a b c d, 
       vars][[Length@monomial]] * Last@monomial
    ]]@"NonzeroPositions" =!= {}
(*  False  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PolynomialQ[a b c + 2 b c a, {b, a, c}]
```

a, b, c do not need to be symbols: [PolynomialQ](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialQ.html)

or use

[Decompose](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Decompose.html)

or use

[FactorList](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FactorList.html)

for more flexibility.

Best seems up to the exactness of the question:

```
SubsetQ[List @@ (a b c + b c a), List @@ (b a c)]
```

(* `True` *)

That is because You do not primarily intent to differentiate between permutations. The basic idea stems from [`PolynomialOrderings`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/PolynomialOrderings.html). The `Apply` of `List` remove the built-ins from the `FullForm` and that is for polynomials `Plus` and `Times`. It then uses lexicographics ordering.

The question is basically for multivariate polynomials in order without the meaning of the order. That is confusing. As seems there is used the set of variate names abc, bac and bca so the induced intent of multivariation is forgotten in the name strings.

```
MemberQ[List @@ (abc + bca), List @@ (bac)]
```

(* False *)

based on the different names. The built-in [`Characters`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Characters.html) is then the link between both approaches.

```
SubsetQ[Characters[ToString[(List @@ (abc + bca))]], 
 Characters[ToString[List @@ (bac)]]]
```

(* `True` *)

Comment: These work on those examples but for example `SubsetQ[List @@ (a b c + b c a), List @@ (b a)]` returns true also when I want that to be false. I want the monomial to appear in the polynomial exactly up to permutation.